How do i print out an output in ARM
Hello im trying to printout an output to show on the users termnial, I want to print out register 12
.global _start
_start:
.data

@An array of 2 words(Dots)
myArray: .word 3, 5, 2
myVector: .word 0xFFFFFFFF, 3, 0
.text
LDR r1, =myArray @ load myArray start address

LDR r5, =myVector @ load myVector start address

LDR r2, [r1] @ r2 = myArray[0] = 3

LDR r3, [r5] @ r3 = myVector[0] = 0xFFFFFFFF (-1)

MUL r4, r2, r3 @ r4 = r2 * r3 = 3 * (-1) = -3

LDR r6, [r1, #4] @ r6 = myArray[1] = 5

LDR r7, [r5, #4] @ r7 = myVector[1] = 3

MUL r8, r6, r7 @r8 = r6 * r7 = 5 * 3 = 15

LDR r9, [r1, #8] @ r9 = myArray[2] = 2

LDR r10, [r5, #8] @ r10 = myVector[2] = 0

MUL r11, r9, r10 @ r11 = r9 * r10 = 2 * 0 = 0

ADD r12, r4, r8 @ r12 = r4 + r8 = -3 + 15 = 12
ADD r12, r12, r11 @ r12 = r12 + r11 = 12 + 0 = 12

@r12 now contains the desired total of 12


Ive tried using
output_format:
.asciz "%d\n"  @ Format specifier for printing an integer with a newline
output_buffer:
.space 20     @ Buffer to hold the output string
but still cant figure out how to display r12

Please update the question to include operating system. The answer depends on the operating system you are using

How are you compiling? If you have access to libc, a function call to printf is probably the most straight forward. Otherwise, a syscall to write can be used, but this will require converting the integer to a char pointer.

Link to the syscall tables for several popular architectures.

Aside, why is this code using so many registers?  Well done on the commenting though.
